# AM and PM times are incorrect?

Tags: php

A few minutes ago I discovered that the forum on my site will incorrectly display AM and PM in the dates. The rest of the time displays correctly and the date.

This is what I have been using for the date times

```php
$date = $row['post_date'];
$realDate = date('m/d/Y', $date);
$realTime = date('H:i:A', $date);
$now = date("m/d/Y H:i:A");
```

Comment: So put date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');  right before date("d-M-Y h:i A");

Comment: Seems like this does not work. I have already set my timezone prior to this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are getting `$date` from database. so you need to set default timezone to your database as well.
you can try

```
SELECT now()
```

to check whether you are getting the correct time. If not then you need to set a timezone for your database by doing below query.

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+5:30';  //this is temp if you restart server this will be gone.
```

in the place of `+5:30` enter you timezone.

here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-do-i-set-the-time-zone-of-mysql) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this format to display *DATETIME* in this fromat like *2019-08-03 11:31:22 AM***

**if you use small a in date format it show am/pm in small letter.**

date('Y-m-d H:i:s A');